How to debug when a process receives a SIGABORT signal in Python
I'm running an application in Python that uses asyncio and it's failing when I'm calling the function await asyncio.gather()
The error I'm getting is just Process 90788 failed to create lock file and the process just exits, without showing any traces of the error. I can see that the process received a SIGABRT signal, but nothing else.
How can I debug this?
I'm using Virtual Studio Code for my debugging, so if it's possible to debug it there, I would prefer it over other solutions, but anything with other tools will be useful as well.

This question is far too vague and open-ended.  You are unlikely to get any help on StackOverflow without showing your source code and probably the traceback.  You debug an asyncio program the same way you debug any program: Read the traceback and figure out what the problem is; put exception handling code into the program; insert print statements into critical sections; write a simplified test program to isolate the problem; Google the error message.

That's part of the problem, there is no traceback

Examine the core-dump. At least on Linux, you probably need to enable core-dumps (hint: ulimit) and then look in a special place (hint: systemd-coredump)
